# uniform cost search making some trouble

Tags: java, netbeans, artificial-intelligence

i am making program for uniform cost search but in my code when i put nodes in priority queue the node overrides... i don't know what's the problem.

for example if node A is already present in a queue with value 10, and if i put node A again with value 20 then the previous node A value also changes.

can any one help?

```
while(!queue.isEmpty())
        {
            Node temp=queue.remove();
            System.out.println(temp.city_name+" "+temp.getPath_cost());
            path.add(temp);
            if(temp==destination)
            {
                break;
            }
            System.out.println(temp.link.length);
            for(int i=0; i<temp.link.length; i++){
                a=temp.link[i].cost;
                b=temp.link[i].getParent().getPath_cost();
                temp.link[i].getNode().setPath_cost(a+b);
                System.out.print(temp.link[i].getNode().city_name+": ");
                System.out.println(temp.link[i].getNode().getPath_cost());
                queue.add(temp.link[i].getNode());
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your node holds the path cost directly, so there is only ever one reference to a node.  Vertexes in a graph (nodes) don't need to know about their path cost for search; instead the search typically implements a wrapper for each node evaluated at the time it is evaluated that stores search specific information, like path cost.  Basically you query the node for it's neighbors (`link` property in your impl) and create a new instance of the wrapper for each neighbor.

All that being said, if you are only looking for the shortest path then you can safely just set the path cost to the min of it's existing path cost and the currently evaluated path cost.  You would start by setting the path cost of each node positive infinity.